# Update and append unless empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Im trying to update a field by appending data to it.
if it contains the data already i wont update it otherwise I will.

if it already contains data i want it to append a comma and space followed by the word. e.g.

```
update myTable 
set  Prefixes = convert(nvarchar(max),Prefixes) + ', abc' 
where MyCol='xyz' and Prefixes not like '%abc%'
```

im trying to get this to work so that if the prefixes column is empty initially it only includes the word 'abc'

and not ', abc'

How can i do this?

Comment: Don't add comma seperated data in **one** column

Comment: Storing a list in a column is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: What you need is a `Prefixes` table with has a `myTable` foriegn key. Then no horrible string manipulation would be required. The query would run faster and your schema would be more flexible. You wouldn't need to use the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: What happens if one prefix `abc`, one is `zabc` and another is `abcd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a `CASE`:

```
update myTable 
set  Prefixes = 
           case 
               when Prefixes is null or Prefixes = ''
               then 'abc'
               else convert(nvarchar(max),Prefixes) + ', abc' 
            end
where MyCol='xyz' and (Prefixes not like '%abc%' or Prefixes is null)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d627c/9)

Comment: would `not like '%, abc'` be better?

Comment: @Jodrell I just kept the original `WHERE` clause that they had.

Comment: What happens if one prefix `abc`, one is `zabc` and another is `abcd`?

Comment: @Jodrell that would be a question for the OP

Comment: @Jordel this column contains comma separated (without spaces and sometimes with spaces) so '%, abc' wont work, given the prefixes im working with i'm unlikely to encounter the issue with your second point. not perfect but it will do for my purpose.

Comment: @bluefeet: I know he has already accepted the answer but your `NOT LIKE` filter does not work if Prefixes is null. [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d627c/6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `null` values of Prefixes before filtering as `NOT LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause as well. [Sql-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d627c/4)

```
update myTable 
set  Prefixes = isnull(nullif(rtrim(Prefixes),'') + ', abc','abc')
where MyCol='xyz' and isnull(Prefixes,'') not like ', abc%'
```