# Stored procedure not updating field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sproc like so, it basically appends a prefix to a field if it does not already exist:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AgSp_UpdateAgTbl_Licensing ](@newPrefix nvarchar, @systemName nvarchar)

AS
BEGIN
       -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
       -- interfering with SELECT statements.
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

update AgTbl_Licensing
set   UrlPrefixes =
           case
               when UrlPrefixes is null or UrlPrefixes = ''
               then @newPrefix
               else convert ( nvarchar( max ), UrlPrefixes) + ', '+@newPrefix
            end
where SystemName = @systemName and (UrlPrefixes not like ('%'+@newPrefix+'%') or UrlPrefixes is null)

END
```

I try and call this like so:

```
Execute AgSp_UpdateAgTbl_Licensing 'eb_', 'EB1';
```

but updates are not being made to the db - how come? i cant debug as i dont have sysadmin

Comment: Does the code wor if you execute it outside of a sproc?

Comment: yes if i put in values instead of using parameter for the update

Comment: I answered this question in a different format yesterday :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610368/update-and-append-unless-empty/14610946#14610946

Comment: @kaf yes thanks, but i now need it in a sproc and to call the sproc separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should declare procedure parameters with length as;

```
@newPrefix nvarchar(50), @systemName nvarchar(50)
```

Otherwise it will take only `FIRST character` of your string and therefore your `WHERE clause fails` to find the records to be updated. And also your parameters are not what you expecting them to be.

Answer (score 1):

(Ignoring that storing multiple values in a single column is almost always worse than properly storing them as rows in a table)

You've declare two parameters to your procedure, both of length 1. Try:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AgTbl_Licensing](@newPrefix nvarchar(100), @systemName nvarchar(100))
```

From [nchar and nvarchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186939.aspx):

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.

Comment: yes i agree, unfortunately the db setup is not in my control. thanks for the explanation this now works, but kafs answer was first